# Python - Get individual elements of dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a column that is a list. I want to extract the individual elements in every list in the column. So given this input dataframe:

```
          A
0     [5, 4, 3, 6]
1     [7, 8, 9, 6]
```

The intended output should be a list:

```
      [5, 4, 3, 6,7, 8, 9, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension with flatten:

```
a = [y for x in df.A for y in x]
```

Or use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from  itertools import chain

a = list(chain.from_iterable(df.A))
```

Or use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
a = np.concatenate(df.A).tolist()
```

Or [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), working for pandas 0.25+:

```
a = df.A.explode().tolist()
```

**Performance** with sample data for 100k rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':[[5, 4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 9, 6]] * 50000})

print (df)

In [263]: %timeit [y for x in df.A for y in x]
37.7 ms ± 3.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [264]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(df.A))
27.3 ms ± 1.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [265]: %timeit np.concatenate(df.A).tolist()
1.71 s ± 86.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [266]: %timeit df.A.explode().tolist()
207 ms ± 3.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#ansev1
In [267]: %timeit np.hstack(df['A']).tolist()
328 ms ± 6.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Which is the fastest option for a dataframe with over > 60,000 rows